# Using tf.train.AdamOptimizer twice for same network

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am trying to fine tune an existing neural network (resnet v2 152) for a new dataset.  The way I have training set up right now is to first train just the last fully connected layer for a few epochs and second to train the entire model for a few epochs.  In order to make this work I defined two optimizers.  When I use the gradient descent optimizer I am able to train the model. However. when I use the AdamOptimizer the model doesn't train.

The most important thing I have noticed is when I include `tf.global_variables_initializer()` using the gradient descent optimizer doesn't train either.  However, it appears `tf.global_varaibles_initializer()` is required to use the AdamOptimizer

If I don't include `tf.global_varaibles_initializer()` and use gradient descent the network trains as expected.

I have included a snippet of the code below. This code is based on the VGG trainer available at: https://gist.github.com/omoindrot/dedc857cdc0e680dfb1be99762990c9c/

```
 variables_to_restore = tf.contrib.framework.get_variables_to_restore(exclude=['resnet_v2_152/logits'])

 init_fn = tf.contrib.framework.assign_from_checkpoint_fn(model_path, variables_to_restore)

 # Initialization operation from scratch for the new "fc" layers

 # `get_variables` will only return the variables whose name starts with the given pattern

 c_variables = tf.contrib.framework.get_variables('resnet_v2_152/logits')
 fc_init = tf.variables_initializer(fc_variables)

 full_variables =tf.contrib.framework.get_variables()
 full_init = tf.variables_initializer(full_variables)

 ## ---------------------------------------------------------------------

 ## Using tf.losses, any loss is added to the tf.GraphKeys.LOSSES collection

 ## We can then call the total loss easily

 loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels, logits=logits)

 ## First we want to train only the reinitialized last layer fc for a few epochs.
 ## We run minimize the loss only with respect to the fc variables (weight and bias).
 fc_optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(args.learning_rate1, name="adam1")
 fc_train_op = fc_optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list=[fc_variables])

 # Then we want to finetune the entire model for a few epochs.

 # We run minimize the loss only with respect to all the variables.

 full_optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(args.learning_rate2, name ="adam2")

 full_train_op = full_optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list=[full_variables])

 init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

No error is given when training but the training and validation accuracies don't update so it appears that the optimizer isn't actually running.

Like I said I think it has to do with the inclusion of `tf.global_variables_initializer()`, but I am not sure how to get around that for using the AdamOptimizer.

Thanks in advance